# How to set custom bold font programmatically - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the font in a UILabel to a custom font but also make it bold without success.  My effort so far is below:

CUSTOM FONT:

```
cell.folderName.font = UIFont.init(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)
```

How do I make the above font also bold/ or italic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This enum can be used for  AmericanTypewriter type.

```
public enum americanTypewriter: String {
case typewriter = "AmericanTypewriter"
    case bold = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
    case condensed = "AmericanTypewriter-Condensed"
    case condensedBold = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold"
    case condensedLight = "AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight"
    case light = "AmericanTypewriter-Light"

    public func font(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: self.rawValue, size: size)!
    }
}
```

For Bold

```
cell.folderName.font = UIFont.init(name: "AmericanTypewriter-Bold", size: 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Font *American Typewriter* doesn't have *italic* style. But it has **bold** style.

So if you need to set bold font, just use

```
"AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
```

---

All *American Typewriter* font's styles:

```
AmericanTypewriter-CondensedBold
AmericanTypewriter-Condensed
AmericanTypewriter-CondensedLight
AmericanTypewriter
AmericanTypewriter-Bold
AmericanTypewriter-Semibold
AmericanTypewriter-Light
```